# Convience methods to convert rospy.Time to datetime.datetime

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I couldn't find any convenience methods to convert rospy.Time to datetime.datetime.  Timezones and other issues make this less trivial than it appears, especially for novice users.

Am I missing something obvious, or is this a textbook case of "nope, not done yet, please submit a patch?"

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/286602/convience-methods-to-convert-rospy.time-to-datetime.datetime/) by [ivaughn](https://answers.ros.org/users/32451/ivaughn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2018-03-26

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-27**:
I would say this is indeed something that just hasn't been done yet. Shouldn't be too difficult though: `rospy.Time` is a Unix stamp, so conversions should be against `UTC`, correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

datetime.datetime to rospy.Time:

```
import datetime

import rospy

dt0 = datetime.datetime.strptime('2018-03-26-14:38:02.012345', '%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S.%f').replace(tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)

rt0 = rospy.Time.from_sec(dt0.timestamp())
```

rospy.Time to datetime.datetime and back:

```
dt1 = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(rt0.to_sec())

rt1 = rospy.Time.from_sec(dt1.replace(tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc).timestamp())
```

---

Originally posted by [rgov](https://answers.ros.org/users/45623/rgov/) with karma: 130 on 2020-11-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4